# RegEx for matching img tags in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub, regex-group

I have two string like:

```
<p class="pic"><img src="image/pic003.jpg" alt="" class="w21em" /></p>

<p class="footnote">oremIpsum loremIpsum oremIpsum loremIpsum<img src="image/pic027.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />oremIpsum loremIpsum<img src="image/pic028.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />`
```

For the first one it should return:

```
[<img src="image/pic003.jpg" alt="" class="w21em" />]
```

and for second it should be

```
[<img src="image/pic027.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />, [<img src="image/pic028.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />
```

For this I wrote a regEx like `para.scan(/\<img.*\>?/)` which outputs first one like

```
["<img src=\"image/pic003.jpg\" alt=\"\" class=\"w21em\" /></p>"]
```

and second one like

```
["<img src=\"image/pic027.jpg\" alt=\"\" class=\"w0em2\" />loremIpsum loremIpsum1/<img src=\"image/pic028.jpg\" alt=\"\" class=\"w0em2\" /> </p>"]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try this Regex pattern: `<img[^>]+\/>`. It will match any self closing img tag. It will match your examples.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you change it to `/(?s)<img.*?>/`

Comment: Are you looking for any specific attribute or value ? Let me know if you are.

Comment: @sln i want to extract img tag within a string

Comment: @dvo- can you plz make it in answer. so that i can mark it as answer. thanks for help

Comment: @ImranNaqvi done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex pattern: `<img[^>]+\/>`.

It will match any self closing img tag, then anything that isn't a `>` character to close the tag. The `\/>` at the end of the pattern will match the SELF closing tag `<img {anything not >} />`

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx

You can design/modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/47gckf/1/):

```
((<img)([A-Za-z0-9"'=_\-.\/\s]+)(\/>))
```

One way to do so, is to list all your chars in a capturing group:

```
([A-Za-z0-9"'=_\-.\/\s]+)
```

You could also modify the right boundary `(\/>)` in case they might be missing forward slash.

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /((<img)([A-Za-z0-9"'=_\-.\/\s]+)(\/>))/gm;
const str = `<p class="pic"><img src="image/pic003.jpg" alt="" class="w21em" /></p>

<p class="footnote">oremIpsum loremIpsum oremIpsum loremIpsum<img src="image/pic027.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />oremIpsum loremIpsum<img src="image/pic028.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />\``;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Ruby Test

```
re = /((<img)([A-Za-z0-9"'=_\-.\/\s]+)(\/>))/m
str = '<p class="pic"><img src="image/pic003.jpg" alt="" class="w21em" /></p>

<p class="footnote">oremIpsum loremIpsum oremIpsum loremIpsum<img src="image/pic027.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />oremIpsum loremIpsum<img src="image/pic028.jpg" alt="" class="w0em2" />`'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```